# Do @@Identity And Scope_Identity Always Return The Record Just Added?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, identity-column

I understand the differences between `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, I think, but I'm struggling to find out exactly how they're generated.

All the documentation tells me that these functions return the ID of the last record added to a table, but if I have a Stored Procedure containing an INSERT statement, and that procedure is part of a heavily-used database that could be getting executed by multiple users at the same time, if those two users both insert a record into the same table fractions of a second apart, is it possible that if I call `@@IDENTITY` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY` from the Stored Procedure right after the INSERT statement, they could actually return the ID of a record inserted by a different user?

I think the answer is that `SCOPE_IDENTITY` would avoid this because, as the name suggests, it gets the identity of the last record added from within the scope of the call to `SCOPE_IDENTITY` (in this case, from within the same Stored Procedure), but since I'm not entirely sure what the definition of the scope is, I don't know if I'm right in thinking this.

Comment: Might be worth reading the remarks section for [`IDENT_CURRENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175098.aspx) which also tries to indicate the differences between the three functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `@@identity` and `scope_identity()` will return the id of a record created by the same user.

The `@@identity` function returns the id created in the same session. The session is the database connection, so that is normally the same thing as the user.

The `scope_identity()` function returns the id created in the same session and the same scope. The scope is the current query or the current stored procedure.

So, the difference between them is if you for example call a procedure from another procedure; if the called procedure inserts a record, using `@@identity` after the call will return that id, but `scope_identity()` will not.

Answer (score 1):

Way back before I knew better I ran a query like

```
select max(id) from table
```

to get the ID of a record I just inserted.  When you use something like this in a production environment where you have multiple users adding records concurrently, bad things happen.

You are implying that @@Identity and scope_identity() work the same way as the query above. That's not the case. They both return the value of identity columns generate via inserts WITHIN THE CURRENT USER'S SESSION ONLY!. Scope_Identity() is useful if you have tables that have triggers on them and the trigger logic does it's own inserts. In those cases @@Identity would return the identity value generated within the trigger, which is probably not what you want. It's for that reason I almost always prefer Scope_Identity() to @@Identity